# Aws IOT to dynamoDB - returns encrypted MQTT messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

My IOT device populates the following data:

```
12-09-2017 12:05:26PeopleIn: 2
```

and this gets streamed in AWS IOT server when I subscribe to the topic.  When I export a message as csv I get the following getting exported:

```
format,payload,qos,timestamp,topic
string,12-09-2017 12:05:26PeopleIn: 2,0,1505190320098,TestSite
```

I am trying to configure AWS DynamoDB to store the above data as a table.  In AWS IOT rules setting I have provided the following:

```
Attribute = *
topicFilter = # (i have also tried with TestSite)
Selected Action = Insert a message into DynamoDB table
```

I created a dynamoDB table with the following settings:

```
Primary Partition Key = timestamp (Number)
```

I have set any sort key. Upon setting up the rule, the data gets populated into the dynamoDB.  However, the timestamp is populated as Unix Timestamp and the data is populated in an encrypted format.  The following is the output that I am getting in AWS DynamoDB.

```
timestamp     data_raw
1505198126899 MTItMDktMjAxNyAxMjowNToyNlBlb3BsZUluOiAy
```

Not sure what I am missing.  What I ideally want is the timestamp + payload.  The desired output would be:

```
timestamp       data
1505198126899   12-09-2017 12:05:26PeopleIn: 2
```

Can someone help?

Comment: The data isn't encrypted... it's *encoded* using Base64.  That string decodes to `12-09-2017 12:05:26PeopleIn: 2`.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I figured it out sometime after posting the question.  I can accept this as an answer if you post it as one.